# Update <li> element class with Javascript for rails loop

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I'm designing an application to store sport games. Now in my notifications I have a list of games to confirm, in my list I have the read and unread class options and also an action to confirm the game. Now when someone confirms a game I don't want a page refresh, however the class should change in read and the button should disappear.

```
    <ul class="notification-body">  
    <% @games.each do |game| 
                    #CONTROLE OP VERWIJDERDE USERS

                    home_user_name = if game.home_user.present?
                        game.home_user.username
                    else
                         t :deleted_user 
                    end 

                    away_user_name = if game.away_user.present?
                        game.away_user.username
                    else
                         t :deleted_user 
                    end 

  %>

        <!-- LOST GAMES -->
            <li class="unread">
                <span>
                <p class="msg">

                  <% if game.home_user.avatar_url.present? %>

                      <%= image_tag(game.home_user.avatar_url, class: 'air air-top-left margin-top-5', width: '50', height: '50') %>

                  <% elsif game.home_user.uid.present? %>

                      <%= image_tag(game.home_user.largeimage, class: 'air air-top-left margin-top-5', width: '50', height: '50') %>

                  <% else %>

                      <%= image_tag(asset_path('picempty.jpg'), class: 'air air-top-left margin-top-5', width: '50', height: '50') %>

                  <% end %>


                        <span class="from"><% if game.loser_user == game.home_user %>Game Won<% else %>Game Lost<% end %> </span>

                        <time><%= time_ago_in_words(game.created_at) %> ago</time>

                        <span class="subject"><%= home_user_name %> <% if game.loser_user == game.home_user %> lost <% else %>won  <% end %> the game with  <%= game.home_score %> - <%= game.away_score %></span>



                        <span class="msg-body">   
                                <%= link_to  game_confirm_game_path(game, game.id), method: :patch, class: "msg", remote: true do %>

                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-success margin-top-5"> <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Confrim</button>

                              <% end %>

                               <%= link_to game_conflict_game_path(game, game.id), method: :patch, class: "msg", remote: true do %>

                                    <button class="btn btn-xs btn-warning margin-top-5"> <i class="fa fa-flag" aria-hidden="true"></i> Flag</button>

                              <% end %>

                         </span>
                </p>        

                </span>
            </li>

    <% end %>
</ul>
<% content_for :scripts do %>
  <script>

$('li a').click(function () {
   // remove existing active class inside li elements
   $('li.unread').removeClass('unread');
  // add class to current clicked element
   $(this).addClass('read');
});

</script>
<% end %>
```

Could someone help me with this Javascript? I kind of a noob in Javascript so sorry if this is a stupid question.

A little recap:

When

```
<%= link_to  game_confirm_game_path(game, game.id), method: :patch, class: "msg", remote: true do %>

<button class="btn btn-xs btn-success margin-top-5"> <i class="fa fa-check" aria-hidden="true"></i> Confrim</button>

<% end %>
```

This button is clicked, it should disappear and also

```
<li class="unread">
```

should change to

```
<li class="read">
```

Comment: -1 for (among several other things) the massive code-dump; this question could easily have been asked with a smaller example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can hide the button, using jQuery `hide()`

```js
$('li a').on('click', function(e){
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).parent('li').removeClass('unread').addClass('read')
 $(this).hide();
})
```

```css
li{
 list-style: none;
 margin: 10px 0;
 padding: 10px 0;
}

.button{
 padding: 5px 10px;
 border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Buttons</title>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
  <li class="unread"><a class="button" href="#">Button</a></li>
  <li class="unread"><a href="#" class="button">Button</a></li>
  <li class="unread"><a href="#" class="button">Button</a></li>
</ul>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script> 
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('body').on('click', '.unread', function() {
  $(this).addClass('read');
  $(this).removeClass('unread');
});
```

Thanks

Comment: Please check your browser console & see if there's any error!

Comment: Downvoted for not addressing the "button should disappear" part of the question.

Comment: Could you please explain what this code does, how is it different from the original code and why it solves the problem?